# Why binomial Distribution?

Tags: statistics

> Let $f(x) = 1/x^2$, $1 < x < ∞$, zero elsewhere, be the pdf of a random variable $X$. Consider a random sample of size 72 from the distribution having this pdf; let $Y$ be the number of observations less than 3. Compute approximately the probability that $Y$ exceeds 50.

According to the solutions manual, $Y$ should follow the binomial distribution but I don't see how this follows.

Comment: I think this is a good question. $Y$ is binomial assuming the random sample is independent and identically distributed, which may be what is meant by 'random sample'. Re answer below binomial is sum of **IID** bernoulli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the i-th sample. You know that $Pr[X_i < 3] = \int_1^3 1/x^2 dx = 2/3$ and $Pr[X_i \geq 3] = 1/3$.

Then all $X_i$ for $i=1...72$ are independant and therefore the probability that more than $50$ $X_i$ are less than $3$ follows a binomial distribution. Precisely, define $Y_i = 0$ if $X_i \geq 3$ and $Y_i = 1$ else. Then you are interessted in $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{72} Y_i$ which is a sum of Bernoulli variables.

Comment: Since binomial is sum of iid bernoulli, you/we are assuming the random sample is iid?